# Pushing to list in Node.js and running out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am pushing functions onto a list to be called later:

```
var insertFunctions = [];

 insertFunctions.push(function(callback){
                    newPlayer.save(function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("error in player save method:", err);
                            callback(err);
                            return;
                        }
                      callback(null,result);
                    });
                });
```

but I am pushing so many of these I think I am blowing up memory. What's the best way to get around this?

I get Node.js exit code 3, which at this point, means blowing memory to me.

Comment: Then you probably have a lot of functions ?

Comment: yes I have a lot of functions

Comment: And they are all different right, you're not pushing the same function over and over again, as that wouldn't make much sense ?

Comment: yes all different anonymous functions, about 130*130*50

Comment: Why do you need the define the same function multiple times?

Comment: If they all look somewhat like that one, that's about 160 characters, to make it easy lets say that's 160 bytes, that would give you 6 710 886 functions for every gigabyte of memory, so you must have a lot ?

Comment: because for each function newPlayer has a different value

Comment: @AlexMills You can't just have `newPlayer` as an argument to your function?

Comment: Try doing it in iterations, separating in batches up to a certain size.  I've had to do the same things and I would queue up to 100 at a time and process those, and then if not done yet I would queue up 100 more and process... You may have trouble if it should all be done in a single "transaction"...

Comment: @Chris yeah that's what I was thinking, will try that

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar no because that would be too object-oriented ;)

Comment: Don't know if this is pertinent but the Google V8 code has a 1GB limitation on buffers.  If lists are allocated from buffers then this limitation would apply.  http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847